# Access only links with given format from a python list

Tags: python, html, regex, python-3.x

I have written a code that fetches the html code of any given site and then fetch all links from it and save it inside a list. My goal is that I want to change all the relative links in html file with absolute links.

Here are the links:

```
src="../styles/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
href="/PhoneBook.ico"
href="../css_responsive/fontsss.css"
src="http://www.google.com/adsense/search/ads.js"
L.src = '//www.google.com/adsense/search/async-ads.js'
href="../../"
src='../../images/plus.png'
vrUrl ="search.aspx?searchtype=cat"
```

These are few links that I have copied from html file to keep the question simple and less error prone.

Following are the different URLs used in html file:

> ```
> http://yourdomain.com/images/example.png
> //yourdomain.com/images/example.png
> /images/example.png
> images/example.png
> ../images/example.png
> ../../images/example.png
> ```

Python code:

```
linkList = re.findall(re.compile(u'(?<=href=").*?(?=")|(?<=href=\').*?(?=\')|(?<=src=").*?(?=")|(?<=src=\').*?(?=\')|(?<=action=").*?(?=")|(?<=vrUrl =").*?(?=")|(?<=\')//.*?(?=\')'), str(html))

newLinks = []
for link1 in linkList:
    if (link1.startswith("//")):
        newLinks.append(link1)
    elif (link1.startswith("../")):
        newLinks.append(link1)
    elif (link1.startswith("../../")):
        newLinks.append(link1)
    elif (link1.startswith("http")):
        newLinks.append(link1)
    elif (link1.startswith("/")):
        newLinks.append(link1)
    else:
        newLinks.append(link1)
```

At this point what happens is when it comes to second condition which is "../" it gives me all the urls which starts with "../" as well as "../../". This is the behavior which I don't need. Same goes for "/"; it also fetches urls starting with "//". I also tried to used the beginning and end parameters of "startswith" function but that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: How about swapping the order of the `elif` statements, such that `../../` is checked *before* `../`?

Comment: This will work but incase I don't want to change some specific url like all those start with "//" need to remain same but when execution will reach "/" it will still compute the other ones with 2 slashes.

Comment: It's dirty, but you could use an empty `elif` statement (using `pass`) in that case...

Comment: Currently the only solution that comes to my mind is instead of using one regex I can create multiples regex for all those url patterns separately, that way I can restrict the number of "/" in url. But i don't like the idea of using so many regex for this work. There has to be some simple way.

Comment: @jojonas you don't get my point if i "pass" the double slash if statement still those urls will again qualify in single slash statement.

Comment: Why would they? If a condition in such an `elif` block is met, the execution continues at the end of the entire `if` block, not at the next `elif` or `else` statement.

Comment: Yes if the first if qualifies and returns "true" still all other elif's will execute. My program is at least working this way.

Comment: @jojonas can't I somehow tell "startswith" to get only links that have strictly 1 slash or only those with 2 slashes like we restrict in regex using {}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `str.count` method:

```
>>> src="../styles/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"
>>> src2='../../images/plus.png'
>>> src.count('../')
1
>>> src2.count('../')
2
```

This seems to be true as `../` only exists at the beginning of urls